# Bot Framework with Node Js extract conversation data with Cosmos DB

Tags: node.js, azure-storage, bots, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I'm developing a chatbot using MS Bot Framework with Node Js.
I'm using both Luis and QnA maker and for the storage I have a Cosmos Db setted. 
I'm using middleware for logging:

```
//Log conversation

const logUserConversation = (event) => {
    console.log('message: ' + event.text + ', user: ' + event.address.user.name);
};

// Middleware for logging
bot.use({
    receive: function (event, next) {
        logUserConversation(event);
        next();
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        logUserConversation(event);
        next();
    }
});
```

How I can extract relevant data maybe querying my Cosmos DB?
Thanks

Comment: This takes broad to the extreme. Please read the FAQs on what is considered on topic here

Comment: Sorry but why broad? I think it's a specific question on a specific argument. I read all the microsoft reference and no one talks about it, I think it's legal to ask

Answer (score 1):

I believe where you would like to start looking would be with [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-intercept-messages).  You can log the messages in your cosmosDB instance for retrieval later.

> The middleware functionality in the Bot Builder SDK enables your bot
>   to intercept all messages that are exchanged between user and bot. For
>   each message that is intercepted, you may choose to do things such as
>   save the message to a data store that you specify, which creates a
>   conversation log, or inspect the message in some way and take whatever
>   action your code specifies.

EDIT: Now that you edited your question that you are already using middleware, I do not understand what your question is at all.

EDIT 2
with QnA maker + LUIS it might look something like this:

```
bot.dialog('Some LUIS Intent', function(session) {
    var query = session.message.text;        
    session.send(query);
    //LOG QUERY HERE
    cog.QnAMakerRecognizer.recognize(query, 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/{QNA APP ID}}/generateAnswer', '{QNA SUBSCRIPTION KEY}', 1, 'intentName', (error, results) => {
        session.send(results.answers[0].answer)
    //LOG ANSWER HERE
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still using it, I modified my question in order to let it visible. How I can Improve the code to extract questions and answers?

Comment: You can correlate your DB entries by conversation ID and timestamp to line up the user questions with bot responses.

Comment: I think that's a pretty big ask... what you are essentially saying is "Please give me code for what I need to do"   Seems like you need to do a lit bit more research and I'm sure you can find what you're looking for.   Perhaps there is a Github Repository with code samples that will help you?

Comment: @TaylorAckley for sure it's not "Please give me code for what I need to do" , it's let me understand how I can do something that is very different. So please ponder the words before adding a comment. Obviously before posting on Stackoverflow I read all the samples on GitHub and they not help much. I repeat, It's a specific question but  if it's a secret ok will remain a secret.

Comment: @JasonSowers my question is that even if I'm using middleware in my Cosmos Db I'm not able to retrieve any question for example. Maybe I do something wrong btw what do you mean with "//LOG QUERY HERE" ?

Comment: Take a look at the example in the [azure document DB repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/blob/master/samples/DocumentManagement/app.js)